# powershell script works but not showing list data(scheduled task)

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script scheduled to get data from list item and send it as email.

I do get the email but the content is empty its not picking up list data.

When i run it from powershell command it works.

I have made sure i ran it using the same credentials i use to login into the sharepoint site.

Any ideas why this is happening.....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to run task with "Highest privileges", and set it to "run whether user is logged in or not", and did you add the SharePoint snapping, and did you add Start-Transcript to see what the actual error is?

Comment: Hi Erik,
      I did run at highest privileges and selected run whether user is logged in or not".I have added "Add Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell " if this is what you meant.
When i run it from powershellGUI it worksbut not when i schedule it.I would add Start-Transcript and see how i go.Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys figured it out.using powershell.exe - command mypowershellscript.psl in a bat file:)
Why is SP2013 using powershell v1?